# Do you know a website that implements a menubar at an angle between 0 and 90 degrees?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I was asked to implement a menu bar that is neither horizontal nor vertical. Here are two example buttons:

[image: Menu bar]

This is something new to me, so to learn how to make this work I'm looking for a site (or better yet, a tutorial) that uses a similar menu bar. Any ideas?

Comment: Hitting the client in the face isn't an option, right?

Comment: If the client is ready to pay for the additional work and/or live with the possible incompatibilities, it's a perfectly reasonable design request IMO.

Comment: The design was not final and the menu is now likely to be changed to a regular horizontal menu. The benefits didn't weigh up to the extra work, the additional maintenance (should the menus ever be rearranged, renamed, added or deleted) and the incompatibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at here

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

**or use like this**

Update:

```
/* for firefox, safari, chrome, etc. */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* for ie */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
/* for opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

**see example** http://jsbin.com/ajoqe/4

Update: 2

or use this extension

Universal CSS Transforms: Rotate(free extension) : http://www.dmxzone.com/go?17422#Overview

> ```
> * Pure CSS based - No Flash required! 
> * Fully cross browser compatible - The Universal CSS Transforms: Rotate
> ```
>
> is a jQuery based, build only with
>   HTML & CSS - no Flash what so ever! It
>   even supports IE6 next to the other
>   major browsers.
>       * Search engine friendly – The Universal CSS Transforms: Rotate is
>   pure HTML and CSS based and generates
>   search engine friendly HTML code that
>   can be nicely indexed by all search
>   engines and web spiders.

update 3

or use this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

> Two JavaScript image handling
>   implementations are supported:
>
> 1. using DXImageTransform filter for Microsoft Internet Explorer
> 2. using Canvas object for other browsers
>
> The library has been tested with:
>
> ```
> * Mozilla FireFox 2.0.0.2
> * Internet Explorer 7.0
> * Opera 9.1 (note Opera 8 is not supported)
> ```

Comment: Looks good if I load the example into Firefox 3.6.*. However, when I rendered the same page in IE 8 and Google Chrome 5.0, the test square was not rotated. http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/600/nogo.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Just because the image is at an angle doesn't mean the hit area (the link) needs to be at an angle...

Comment: That's not my only concern. Because the menu is not aligned horizontally, I cannot use the same red brick for every menu option. I have to work with an image map or all-image <li> items to begin with and then I have to add a drop-down menu to every item, which is another issue altogether.

Comment: Oh, dear god... They want dropdowns from an angled menu? That's going to cause a lot of usability issues.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your opinion. Judging from some comments I've seen in this thread, this diagonal menu is a bad idea and will require me to overcome lots of technical roadblocks, so maybe it's not worth the pain. I'll contact the designer to see what he can do using a horizontal menu.

Answer (score 3):

Stuff like this is usually done using images and - if you want a non-rectangular click area - using image maps. It's not very difficult to do but a lot more work than a straightforward `ul`.

The CSS `rotate` capabilities are not wide-spread enough yet to achieve a consistent effect in all browsers, but it might be an option to build a cross-browser menu that looks okay unrotated, and great when rotated.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Transformations are currently supported only via vendor-specific CSS attributes. See this blog for [cross-browser support](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/).

Comment: Looks good if I load the example into Firefox 3.6.*. However, when I rendered the same page in IE 8 and Google Chrome 5.0, the test square was not rotated. http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/600/nogo.jpg